# Installing grunt globally failed and I can't find it on npmjs.org

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs

I'm getting this error when I run npm install - ideas on why this might be happening?
I've never had a problem installing other libraries globally and I can't find grunt on http://search.npmjs.org/

```
npm install -g grunt
npm ERR! Error: Not found: grunt@''
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["latest","devel"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:410:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:403:17
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:136:7)
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:36:9)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/**
npm ERR! node -v v0.4.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.103
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/**/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: I would start by upgrading your Node.js and NPM. You're currently running very old versions. Don't know why you didn't find Grunt on NPM, but it is: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt

Comment: Thanks - it ended up being a matter of upgrading

Comment: You should answer your own question if you found the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just having to upgrade node and npm